# Boot back to Windows?

Tags: windows-8

I'm sure this question has been asked thousands of times but here I go: so I installed the latest Ubuntu (dual booting with my Windows 8) and it keeps booting to the USB I used. If I take it out it try's to search for it and fails obviously so it says it can't find a boot disk. I need to get back to my windows how do I do this?!

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution to problems like this is to run boot-repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can run this from within Ubuntu, or there's also a CD image available from the above linked site.

Boot-repair is capable of fixing problems with Windows boot, not just Ubuntu, and should even work for dual-boot systems.

As for the reason for your problem, it's most likely that the Ubuntu installer modified your computer's boot information in UEFI in a way that is not compatible with the way you were booting before.  This is bad news for your Windows partition as it has lost the ability to boot.  It is possible that you could solve that problem with the Windows repair CD, but you would then still not be able to boot Ubuntu, and in some cases it may require a re-install of Windows which is not ideal.  Boot-repair is more likely to be successful.

Run boot-repair carefully and don't change any of its default settings unless you have fully read the page I linked and/or its documentation.